# 2 regex work correctly independently but they don't when combined

Tags: regex, regex-group

I would like to split up a string based on punctuation, while keeping the punctuation, and also if a string is wrapped in curly braces delete the curly braces but not the word.

My current regex works ALMOST perfectly. It does not capture a punctuation if it is the last character in a string. Thank you for your help

```
// const re = /([.!\"'/$:\d]+)/g;
// const re = /{(.*?)}/g

const re =  /([.!\"'/$:\d]+)| {(.*?)}/g

const delimiter= new RegExp(re);
const sentences = sentence.split(delimiter);
sentences = sentences.filter(Boolean);

console.log(sentences)
```

Input:

```
const sentence = `Lorem ipsum {dolor sit} amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et {dolore magna aliqua}. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat! Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum?`
```

Actual Output:

```
[
  'Lorem ipsum',
  'dolor sit',
  ' amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et',
  'dolore magna aliqua',
  '.',
  'Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat',
  '!',
  'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur',
  '.',
  'Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum?'
]
```

Desired Output:

```
[
  'Lorem ipsum',
  'dolor sit',
  ' amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et',
  'dolore magna aliqua',
  '.',
  'Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat',
  '!',
  'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur',
  '.',
  'Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum',
  '?'
]
```

Comment: Please add an example sentence, and show what you're expecting to get as a result.

Comment: Try ``/([!-\/:-@[-`{-~])|\s*{([^{}]*)}/``

Comment: Added examples for clarification. Just need to capture that last character if it's a punctuation

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! Is there a way to exclude "," in your regex?

Comment: Yes, you may use ``/(?!,)([!-\/:-@[-`{-~])|\s*{([^{}]*)}/``, or ``/([ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=[\]{};':"\\|.<>\/?~])|\s*{([^{}]*)}/``

Comment: Sorry, the second one should be without space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
/\s*{([^{}]*)}|([`!@#$%^&*()_+=[\]{};':"\\|.<>\/?~-])/
```

Or -  a bit more compact:

```
/\s*{([^{}]*)}|(?!,)([!-\/:-@[-`{-~])/
```

Both `` [`!@#$%^&*()_+=[\]{};':"\\|.<>\/?~-] `` and `` (?!,)([!-\/:-@[-`{-~]) `` patterns match all ASCII punctuations and symbols other than `,`. The main difference is the `\s*` part: your space before `{{` was an obligatory pattern, with `*`, `\s*` matches zero or more occurrences of whitespace chars.

JS demo:

```js
var sentence = "Lorem ipsum {dolor sit} amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et {dolore magna aliqua}. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat! Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum?";
var delimiter =  /\s*{([^{}]*)}|([`!@#$%^&*()_+=[\]{};':"\\|.<>\/?~-])/;
var sentences = sentence.split(delimiter).filter(Boolean);
console.log(sentences);
```

Comment: I noticed that if the {} is the first character/word it doesn't work. e.g. `"{this}"` or `"{not} this"` returns `["{", "this", "}"]` or `["{", "not", "}", "this"]` 
Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @Jonathan Looks like you need to swap the alternatives, ``/\s*{([^{}]*)}|([`!@#$%^&*()_+=[\]{};':"\\|.<>\/?~-])/``, see https://regex101.com/r/OVFgJ2/1